# Single close event handler for multiple jquery dialogs

Tags: jquery

```
    var options = {  modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            height: 500,
            minWidth: 700,
            minHeight: 500,
            overlay: true,
            position: ["center", 200],
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }
    };

 $('#dialog').dialog(options);
$('#dialog1').dialog(options);
 $('#dialog2').dialog(options);
```

I want to have single event handler on close of any dialog ,So that I can apply a generic function on close of any dialog in project.

Answer (score 0):

Pass teh close callback as an option

```
var options = {
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    minWidth: 700,
    minHeight: 500,
    overlay: true,
    position: ["center", 200],
    overlay: {
        opacity: 0.5,
        background: "black"
    },
    close: function (e, ui) {
        console.log('close')
    }
};
```

---

If you want to target any dialog in the page then

```
$(document).on('dialogclose', function (e, ui) {
    console.log('close any jQuery UI dialog')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/589z4dtg/)

Comment: but i want event handler for close event ..that was just a basic example beacuse options can be different in different files..

and suppose multiple developers are working on single project , then we have to tell each and every one to create close callback thats why we need single event handler so that if any dialog is created from anywhere how i could we detect that any dialogue is fired a close event.